# how to re-enable jRating star <div>?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the plugin jRating.

```
http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jRating/demo
```

With jRating once we click on rating the rating get submitted and the rating stars become disabled.
I have situation where I have to re-enable and disable based on the logged in user and sort of information
I had look into the jRating.jquery.js and found this line

```
$(this).unbind().css('cursor','default').addClass('jDisabled');    //line 132
```

which disables the div. 
`this`in the line 132 above refer to a div with id `10_5`.
How can I re-enable the starring div with id `10_5`?

Comment: in jRating.jquery.js jDisabled is a variable which is set true or false

Comment: Seems that the unbind function at line 132 unbinds the onmouseover event. So may be I can bind that event back and get the code running.